# Div space despite no padding

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a website with a navbar, followed by two columns. For some reason the navbar shows up with padding on the top, left and right, even though I haven't added any of those properties.

The navbar and the two columns are supposed to have the same width, which is currently not the case:

[image]

```css
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans') format('woff');
    }
    
    html {
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .nav {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav a {
      float: left;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 14px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .nav a:hover {
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #ffffff;
    }
    
    .nav a:active {
    color: black;
    }
    
    .nav-right {
      float: right;
    }
    
    .nav img {
      float: left;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 4em;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #hero-image {
      max-width: 50vw;
    }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" class="home">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="nav">
        <a href="/">Title</a>
        <div class="nav-right">
          <a href="/">Link</a>
          <a href="/explore">Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
              1
          </div>
          <div class="column">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/raVKyuB.jpg" id="hero-image" alt="Attraction">
          </div>
        </div>
          <footer>
             <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
       </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What happens if you explicitly set padding to 0 on the body? `body {padding: 0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your styling for what I think should be the correct CSS coding as of today's standard. Flex layout, descriptive HTML5 tags, etc. You can find more comments within the code.

```css
@font-face {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans') format('woff');
    }
    
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 100%;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    nav {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    nav > div {
      padding: 1rem 0px; /* typical for distances */
      box-sizing: border-box; /* count padding into width, important for flex children */
    }
        
    nav > .left {
      flex: 1 1 auto; /* automatically fill out any empty space */
    }
    
    nav a {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 1rem; /* typical for distances */
    }
    
    nav a:hover {
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #ffffff;
    }
    
    nav a:active {
      color: black;
    }
                
    section {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .column {
      min-height: 50vh;
      padding: 1rem; /* typical for distances */
      flex-basis: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box; /* count padding into width, important for flex children */
    }
    
    .column.right { /* placing the image as a background for easier adaptation to different screen widths */
      background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/raVKyuB.jpg');
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" class="home">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
      <nav class="nav">
        <div class="left">
          <a href="/">Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <a href="/">Link</a>
          <a href="/explore">Link</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <section>
          <div class="left column">
              1
          </div>
          <div class="right column">
          </div>
      </section>
      
      <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
       </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have this:

```
.nav-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

which causes 10px space right of the `.nav-right` element.

And second, you should add `margin: 0` to `html` and `body` to avoid the default margin of these.

Comment: I thought your suggestion worked, but not completely. At first glance everything is fixed, but if you view the page in full-size and refresh (wait a few seconds after each refresh), there is a white space on the right side of the nav bar (not left or top). CSS has been updated to latest version. Tested with Chrome and Edge on Windows 10.

Comment: using exactly your code and adding the suggested `html, body { margin: 0; }` seemed to fix the issue on my CodePen. If you're still seeing the issue, then you may not have provided all the details necessary for us to test properly

Comment: Don't use float anymore to position elements. There is `flex` that should be used instead. You even have a clear-fix hack because you're using floats.